# Manual particle emission, rotate the whole particle system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, particle-system

I'm manually emitting particles from a particle system. It's supposed to replace multiple instances of the same component, so at once multiple emit positions are being used like so:

```
private IEnumerator EmitParticlesGradually(Vector3 spawnPos)
{
    yield return _wfs;

    var totalParticles = (int) (rateOverTime * emissionDuration);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalParticles; i++)
    {
        var randomPoint = (Random.insideUnitCircle * _shapeModule.radius);

        var position = spawnPos + new Vector3(randomPoint.x, Y, randomPoint.y);

        _combinedParticleSystem.Emit(new ParticleSystem.EmitParams {position = position}, 1);

        yield return _emissionInterval;
    }
}
```

This coroutine is simultaneously started with different positions and it works fine as long as I don't need the whole thing rotated.

The particles use `Velocity over lifetime` module for their movement, which is downwards and tilted on the horizontal side. When the emission happens the current camera rotation is being used to ensure the spawn angle is always the same regardless of where you're looking. However I cannot change the rotation of the particle system when I'm manually emitting particles since there are multiple instances and therefore multiple rotations are needed, making it jitter.

In essence when using regular multiple instances of particle system I would just change the rotation of the holding transform, however this doesn't appear to be possible when using `ParticleSystem.Emit()`, what workaround are there?

Comment: If this is for efficiency I'd suggest to benchmark it against using multiple PS components as this creates a lot of garbage in unmaged code - I'd wager using multiple particle systems is actually more performant.

Comment: @Absinthe It is not, it provides a significant performance boost compared to the standard method. The particle system it's replacing contains 5-6 subemitters and has some of the expensive module enabled such as collisions.